# How to specify message body encryption method for Rampart?

Tags: apache-axis, ws-security, policy, encryption-asymmetric, rampart

I am working with Axis2 1.6.1 + Rampart 1.6.1 on the server side of a web service.

I've been asked to employ RSA 1.5 for message body encryption. From what I can tell (by inspecting captured SOAP messages), the default algorithm to encrypt the message body is Triple DES CBC. So I want to change that to RSA 1.5.

I am assuming that there is some property I need to set in my server policy XML file. However, I cannot figure out what property that might be. I have looked at example policy files, [this page about WSS configuration](http://ws.apache.org/wss4j/config.html), and [this page about Rampart configuration](https://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/rampart/rampartconfig-guide.html), and various blogs and what-not.

If someone can point out an example policy or relevant configuration docs or whatever, I'll be very grateful. Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to the [WS-Security Policy Specification section 6.1](http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/v1.3/os/ws-securitypolicy-1.3-spec-os.html#_Toc212617835). Why do you want to use RSA ? The given algorithm suites in the spec don't use RSA for encryption.

Comment: Thanks for the reference, that's very helpful. I was looking for RSA because that's what the spec I was given says. Perhaps it's an oversight on the part of the person who wrote the spec.